# Is there any ARXML template for create Ethernet cluster description and SOME/IP setting?

Tags: autosar

Is there any ARXML templates that just like the "AUTOSAR_MOD_ECUConfigurationParameters.arxml" for developers to create Ethernet cluster description and SOME/IP setting?

Comment: The AUTOSAR_MOD_ECUConfigurationParameters.arxml is actually a module definition for the standarized AUTOSAR BSW components configuration sets described in each SWS. For SystemDescriptions, there is no "template", but a model, as described in the AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate.pdf (incl references to other TPSs). There is the autosar-xxxxx.xsd XML Schema, which defines the XML format, or you can also use the SystemTemplate to check, what can/should be defined. artop.org provides an EMF Model with editors for editing ARXML files.

Comment: Thanks you kesselhaus. Yet, as you said, the file works as a model that defined the definition of SWC. And I just want know which file is input so that I can extract the definitions in xxx.arxml and shows that via HMI to config communication matrix.

Comment: As I just said before, the xsd schema describes the contents what can be done in an arxml file, but there are some things (AUTOSAR validation rules & constraints), that can not be expressed in XSD. That's why tool vendors add additional validation rules/checks in their tools. If you rather be based on EMF model, artop is the best "almost" free shot of tooling (including splitable support!), e.g. together with Sirius, you can create diagrams and tables based on model elements Though, there was someone here on SO asking about some XQuery based problem, in case you base your tool on plain ARXML.

Comment: Got it, you really help me a lot.May I have your Email, for discussion when I need learn from you someday?